# How to change animation duration dynamically?

Tags: ios, animation

I have an animation that scrolls a UIScrollView(mimicking the star wars intro screen of sorts), im looking for the best way to: when the user presses a button the animation goes faster. Which sort of means that i need to reduce the duration of the ongoing animation? (or at least thats the way that im thinking of it).

What is the best way to achieve this?

UPDATE: this the current code i have (is using ruby motion but that should not be a problem.)

```
class StoryController < UIViewController
  def loadView
    @layout = StoryLayout.new
    self.view = @layout.view
    @scroll_view = @layout.get(:scroll_view)
    view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints
  end

  def viewDidAppear(animated)
    super
    self.performSelector(:animate_story, withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
  end

  def animate_story
    @story_animation = UIView.animateWithDuration(
      80,
      delay: 0,
      options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear,
      animations: -> {
        @scroll_view.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 2000)
      },
      completion: -> (finished) {
        story_animation_completed
      }
    )
  end

  def story_animation_completed
    parent = self.parentViewController
    parent.pop
    parent.push(NameController.new)
  end


  def keyCommands
    [
      UIKeyCommand.keyCommandWithInput("o", modifierFlags: 0, action: :accelerate_animation),
    ]
  end


  def accelerate_animation
    # Here goes the code that would change the duration
  end
```

Comment: can you post the code you have already

Comment: remove old animation add new one onclick.

Comment: @steve i have updated the question with the relevant part of the code, i can understand obj-c or swift  so dont worry about the ruby syntax.